# How to update identical lines of data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm working in SQLserver. I have several lines of exact identical data like this:

```
hm       dep        num
517     577578  308330148120004
517     577578  308330148120004
517     577578  308330148120004 
517     577578  308330148120004
```

I want to update the 'hm' section with the data's row number, like this:

```
hm       dep        num
1       577578  308330148120004
2       577578  308330148120004
3       577578  308330148120004 
4       577578  308330148120004
```

How shoud I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an updateable [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) along with the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  hm,
            dep,
            num,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dep, num ORDER BY hm)
    FROM    T
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     hm = RowNumber;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c38/3)**

This basically ranks your identical rows in any order, then after assigning that order sets the column `hm` to the row number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hm ORDER BY hm) AS hm
FROM TableName
```

I´m writing this off the top of my head so it may not be 100%.
You can see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx for ROW_NUMBER details.